# Label movement not making sense?

Tags: vb.net, location, label

I am playing around in vb.net and decided to make a 23x18 grid of labels, 234 labels in total. Each label is titled 'Label(x)' from 1 to 234. I have another label which, when I press a key (wasd), should move in the corresponding direction. In most cases it does this correctly, but in others it jumps over them, skipping one or maybe two labels altogether. I can't imagine why this is.

```
Dim lab As Label
Dim x As Integer

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown1(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    For x = 1 To 234
        lab = Controls("Label" & x)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.A And lab.Location = New Point(lblPlayer.Location.X - 20, lblPlayer.Location.Y) And lab.Text <> "#" Then
            lblPlayer.Location = lab.Location
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.D And lab.Location = New Point(lblPlayer.Location.X + 20, lblPlayer.Location.Y) And lab.Text <> "#" Then
            lblPlayer.Location = lab.Location
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.W And lab.Location = New Point(lblPlayer.Location.X, lblPlayer.Location.Y - 13) And lab.Text <> "#" Then
            lblPlayer.Location = lab.Location
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.S And lab.Location = New Point(lblPlayer.Location.X, lblPlayer.Location.Y + 13) And lab.Text <> "#" Then
            lblPlayer.Location = lab.Location
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

I have considered it could possibly be due to a wrong label location in the grid (which I have confirmed to be false) but even if that was so, the label shouldn't move at all, rather than jumping. The labels it jumps over are consistent, but I honestly cannot see why those specific labels are being skipped.

I have since added a sub which makes every label the 'player' has passed over change colour, and that has shown me that it doesn't even pass over the 'jumped' label, it skips them completely, as they remain the same colour. I honestly cannot see how this code allows for that, as it should only check for the label the in the correct position, and will only move if that label is found there.

Am I having a complete brain fart here? Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask questions as specific as this. Please direct me to the correct place if this is not the place for scenarios such as this.

Comment: If you find the "correct" label you should **exit** the `for loop` eg `If e.KeyCode = Keys.A And........ Then` `lblPlayer.Location = lab.Location` `Exit For`

Comment: I usually add label to a list object instead of references controls by name which is slow.        Dim labels As New List(Of Label)
        For i = 0 To 100
            Dim newLabel As New Label
            labels.Add(newLabel)
        Next

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε
This actually solved the problem. I assume that the problem was due to the method in which I created the grid. 
It would find the correct label, but then continue searching with the new location in mind, thus finding any labels which appear later in the list, numerically, that match what would be the next location to find. Thanks for that, knew it would be something simple!